# Integrating $\int_{C}z^{\alpha}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

$\int_{C}z^{\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is an arbitrary complex number, C is the positively oriented unit circle $|z| = 1$ and $1^{\alpha} = 1$. Does anyone know how to handle the final requirement of $1^{\alpha} = 1$? I have: $$\int_{C} z^{\alpha}dz = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\cos(t) + i\sin(t))^{\alpha}(-\sin(t) + i\cos(t))dt$$

Comment: For non-integer $\alpha$ you are using the principal value of $z^\alpha$?  Or maybe you are requiring that the integrand is continuous on $[-\pi,\pi]$?

Comment: I'm not sure. The exercise statement does not clarify this.

Comment: The reaon for the requirement $1^\alpha = 1$ is because complex exponentiation can be quite hairy. Remember that $e^{2\pi i} = 1$. This might lead to, for instance, $1^i = \left(e^{2\pi i}\right)^i = e^{2\pi i \cdot i} = e^{-2\pi} \neq 1$. They want to avoid that kind of trouble.

Comment: Oh, okay. That does make sense to have that requirement. I'm still confused on how to proceed from my latest step though.

Answer (score 0):

The need to integrate functions of the form, $z\mapsto z^{\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is not an integer, comes up in certain contour integration applications of integration. But in that case, we typically choose a "[keyhole contour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration#Example_.28IV.29_.E2.80.93_branch_cuts)". But we have to specify which branch we are using, in such a way we do not run into any difficulties with the non-continuity of the function.